# error when import json file in parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a json file and I want import it into parse.com but when it import successful I can not open file Image. then I export, image url in json file export changed. 
thanks for help.

```html
import file:

{
        "HasChildrent": false,
        "HasIcon": true,
        "Image": {
            "__type": "File",
            "name": "tfss-26822327-8847-4dfc-ac43-68c78d0c86e0-catDrink.png",
            "url": "http://files.parsetfss.com/7fcdfdb0-3ba3-424f-a802-237c93ce4a4c/tfss-26822327-8847-4dfc-ac43-68c78d0c86e0-catDrink.png"
        },
        "Name": "Đồ uống",
        "Parent": "3PIsu5bDJF",
        "createdAt": "2015-03-10T08:02:20.496Z",
        "objectId": "iYAtg437j2",
        "updatedAt": "2015-04-08T04:15:45.763Z"
    },

and export file:

{
        "HasChildrent": false,
        "HasIcon": true,
        "Image": {
            "__type": "File",
            "name": "tfss-26822327-8847-4dfc-ac43-68c78d0c86e0-catDrink.png",
            "url": "http://files.parsetfss.com/ef258b50-635b-4853-aa61-a2213500766e/tfss-26822327-8847-4dfc-ac43-68c78d0c86e0-catDrink.png"
        },
        "Name": "Đồ uống",
        "Parent": "3PIsu5bDJF",
        "createdAt": "2015-03-10T08:02:20.496Z",
        "objectId": "iYAtg437j2",
        "updatedAt": "2015-04-08T04:15:45.763Z"
    },
```